# Reuse reducers per same component

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Say that I've written my own reducer `counter` and the corresponding component `<Counter />` created by connect().

I then create a `store` to hold the data of `counter` and render `<Counter />` inside `<Provider />`, like this:

```
const store = createStore(counter);

render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Counter />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Till now, everything goes right.

But when I thought that I can easily reuse my reducer `counter` and component `<Counter />` and tried to render multiple counters in one page, I found myself struggled...

The first thought came to my mind is to create multiple `store`s and `<Provider />`s to accomplish this, like:

```
const store1 = createStore(counter);
const store2 = createStore(counter);

render(
  <div>
    <Provider store={store1}>
      <Counter />
    </Provider>
    <Provider store={store2}>
      <Counter />
    </Provider>
  </div>,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

This approach works, but conflicts with the "one store per application" principle of Redux.

Later I tried lots of different approaches to accomplish this with only one `store` at the same time reusing as much what I've created as I can (for now, reducer `counter` and component `<Counter />`).

The final (and workable) approach I came out is to write a new reducer `multiCounters` and a new connected component `MultiCounters`, then use it:

```
// new reducer
const multiCounters = (state, action) => {
  ...
};

// new connected component
const Counters = ({...}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Counter {...} />
      <Counter {...} />
      ...
    </div>
  );
};
const MultiCounters = connect(...)(Counters);

// render
const store = createStore(multiCounters);

render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <MultiCounters />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

This approach works and meet the "one store" principle, but I have to write another bunch of code to wrap the component I want to reuse. No to mention what's really being reused is only the React component `<Counter />`, the reducer `counter` for single counter becomes useless in this situation...

**Are there any smarter approaches to reuse components (also reducers, maybe?) in ReactRedux?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could create another wrapper Container, for example `<CountersPage />`that is connected to redux store and pass the counter data as Props to children Components (the `<Counter />` you created).

For instance,

```
const store = createStore(counter);
render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <CountersPage />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

And the wrapper component is very similar to your `<MultiCounters />` but the data is pass by props.

```
class CountersPage extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Counter counter={this.props.counter} />
        <Counter counter={this.props.counter} />
      </div>
   );
  }
};
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { counter: state.counter }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(CountersPage)
```

Note that `<Counter />` does not connect to redux store and become a stateless/presentational component. `<CountersPage />` is its stateful parent components(Container).

See the differences in this article by the creater of Redux: https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0#.uvvzhk1eu